# Save text file with code page UTF-8 in Axapta 3.0

Tags: axapta, x++

How do I make a text file with code page UTF-8 in Axapta 3.0?

I cannot use

`myFile = new CommaIo(myFileName, 'W', 65001);`

as we can in newer versions of Axapta. In Axapta 3.0 `new CommaIo` only have the first two parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not worked in 3.0, but I have a few ideas for you that might send you the right way.

1) Do you have `CommaTextIo` or `TextIo`? Those are the objects where you can specify a code page.

2) Look in the `AOT` and see if you have a macro called `#File`, and inside if you have `#utf8Format(65001)`, use the X-Ref (or Ctrl+F) to find other places in the system that use it. Then you can see how they might accomplish `UTF-8`

3) See if you can combine `CommaIo` with some .NET code, or just manually generated a CSV. Perhaps generate your CSV  and write it, then read it and re-write it using a method like below (from `MetadataXMLGenerator` job):

```
void write(str _directory, str _name, str _text)
{
    str path;
    ;

    _text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex::Replace(_text, '\n', '\r\n');
    if (!System.IO.Directory::Exists(_directory))
    {
        System.IO.Directory::CreateDirectory(_directory);
    }
    path = System.IO.Path::Combine(_directory, _name);
    System.IO.File::WriteAllText(path, _text, System.Text.Encoding::get_UTF8());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alex.
I'll look into this.